# Tips for the proper statistical method for analysing 104 Datasets in RStudio

Tags: anova, t-test, modeling

for my last major homework before my masters in musicology I am trying to do a characterization of loudspeakers through psychoacoustic parameters. Though I am very interested in statistics I am either blind on what to do, or am in it over my head...

So now project in short (and dirty): I have 26 loudspeakars models of different sizes, brands and price points, that were recorded playing 4 different musical pieces. These recording were processed with an automated feature extraction program, resulting in 104 datasets that contain 8 different psychoacoustical parameters sampled twice a second for 30 seconds, so around 60 data points.

My goal is to show that within each of the musical pieces all speakers perform uniquely, but doing 4x 25! t-tests per seems no the right way to do, neither does an ANOVA seem to make sense.

I've beem on this too long and my brain is fried, so maybe somebody can help me out :)!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "perform uniquely" means and how you would expect that to be manifested in the data?

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating further! I already did t-tests that show that one parameter between two speakers in same song have significant differences in variance. Example: one parameter is the spectral centroid, which for bigger speakers which I would expect to be lower (and it is...). but I now have 8 parameters for a total of 26 pairs of speakers over 4 songs. Doing those amounts of t-tests or anovas does not make sense...I hope this explanation helps a bit...

Comment: Can you please add this clarifications as an edit to the post? Not everybody reads comments!